# Type Mismatch error in Initialization form code calling an Access data table

Tags: sql, ms-access, excel, vba

I am now encountering an issue in my project that seems to have occurred without any code alteration.  As a background, my project got corrupted so I consequently redid the entire project in another workbook to work around the corruption.  I'm slightly concerned I'm facing the same problem again but hopefully not.

My program is throwing the following error when prompted to pull up the first forms that require connection to my Access data table: "Run-time Error -2147352571 (80020005): Type Mismatch".  Instead of highlighting a specific line of code in the Initialization portion of the form, VB highlighted only the line of code where the form was actually called out.  I'm confident the issue is in this section based on previous issues I've had with form code.  Below is the code with which I believe I'm having the issue:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call SetConnection
    'Modify [Week] data type
    Connection.Execute "ALTER TABLE Raw_Data ALTER COLUMN [Week] DATE;"
    'Define recordset
    Set Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    With Recordset
        .Open "SELECT DISTINCT [Week] from Raw_Data;", Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
        .MoveFirst
    End With
    With Select_Week_Ending_Form.Week_Ending_Listbox
        .Clear
        Do
            .AddItem Recordset![Week]
            Recordset.MoveNext
        Loop Until Recordset.EOF
    End With
    Set Recordset = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

I'm very new to SQL code so I apologize in advance if it's a simple error with respect to that; but again the code was working fine previously.  If you need any additional code, please let me know.  Thanks for your help.

Jordan

Comment: Change the error handling setting to break in class modules then step into the code so you can find the actual error line. BTW you don't need to loop to populate the control: `Select_Week_Ending_Form.Week_Ending_Listbox.Column = Recordset.GetRows`. I'd also use different variable names that aren't the same as the types. ;)

Comment: What data type is [week]? Is there data in the Raw_Data the table?

Comment: [Week] is Date date type (General Date to be specific).  I changed the setting to Break In-Class Modules and now the error handler is highlighting the following line of code: ".AddItem Recordset![Week]".  I'm trying to populate the listbox with only one column of data from the Access data table.  Rory, will your suggestion work under that condition?  Thanks.

Comment: Also, I have a fair number of empty entries in my Access data table (about 2,000 filled entries, seems to go to about row 60,000 being empty).  Could this be creating the Type Mismatch error by any chance, with the null values in the table creating the error?

Comment: It does now work but now I am getting an empty first value in my listbox even though there are no real entries in my data table that have an empty value in [Week].  What could be causing this and how can I fix it?  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you need to ignore those: `"SELECT DISTINCT [Week] from Raw_Data WHERE Week Is Not Null;"`

Comment: Interestingly, that doesn't work for the code above but does work for my other very similar form where the user selects a part number instead of a week.  Essentially the same code.  I'm definitely puzzled by this.  The extra bit of code that the code above contains compared to the part number selection form is the portion where the [date] value is converted back to DATE format.  The part number selection code doesn't contain this section.  Any thoughts?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Two things I would check  1:Change Do -- Loop until to Do While Not Recordset.EOF and 2: check the Select_Week_Ending_Form.Week_Ending_Listbox format

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating the looping in the Initialization code seems to have fixed the problem.  I will now implement this throughout my program.  Thanks so much!!!